# VBA macro not selecting date range on Italian-locale PC

Tags: excel, vba, date, range, locale

The below line of code works great on a UK locale PC, but selected nothing when run on an Italian PC.  The values for the two date variables 'DateLow' and 'DateHigh' are taken from cells in the workbook.

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tblMasterfile").Range.AutoFilter Field:=8, _
        Criteria1:=">" & Format(DateLow, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & Format(DateHigh, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

Has anyone encountered this before?

Answer (score 0):

Try a repair install on MS Office and make sure that all of the default settings are the same.